# Module not found everytime when I switch the branches

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I checkout between branches, it gives me errors  that Module not found: and bla bla bla (for example, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-redux' in 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FS\Note App\Frontend\src\components'), even so before this everything was ok and worked normal and of course all necessary modules had been installed.So I have to install react-redux and @reduxjs/toolkit again and again.
It all started after I clone the project on another computer, the project is mine, I did it on my old computer. I did as before with cloned projects: clone it, then run npm install.

Answer (score 0):

Without much more context I'm just taking a guess here.

If you have `node_modules` committed in your repository it's possible that when you switch branches the libraries you have installed in `node_modules` could be overwritten with whatever you have in your branch.

Add `node_modules` into your `.gitignore` (if you are using git)

Comment: node_modules is added to .gitignore